# Make application 'single file' and get rid of XML config file

Tags: vb.net, file, exe

I have this pretty simple application, it uses a webService to transfer data to my servers DataBase. Now it is very important for me to keep this application as one single file, and not having some XML files needed for it to work, but this is the case. I think the XML file holds the information to this webService, so without it the application crashes. Is there a way to get the application to work without this XML file, or a way to put the XML inside the exe archive?

Any way to accomplish this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is [invoke a web service programmatically](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/39138d08-aa08-4c0c-9a58-0eb81a672f54/) (without a Visual-Studio-added web reference).  Another potentially useful link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CallWebServicesDynamic.aspx).

I imagine all of the configuration settings that exist in an app.config file can be hard-coded in one way or another, the various config sections will just require varying degrees of ingenuity to make it happen.

Comment: .. Seems like a big work-around, is it really impossible to do this any other way? I am using visual-studio, there ain't something I can check to let the application build as one single .exe?

Comment: @Jacob Kofoed: Not that I've ever heard of, though if somebody can correct me on that I'd like to know.  But when you think about it, what you essentially need is the web service code created by adding a web reference in Visual Studio.  You _may_ be able to try creating a web reference normally and looking through the generated code for any configuration references and replacing them with hard-coded values.  It's certainly worth a try.

Comment: Yeah, I have found that only a very few values are required for the application to run. I think I can hard-code this at initialization. Is there a way to write XML inside vb.net code?

Comment: @Jacob Kofoed: That depends on what you mean by "write XML."  If you're just talking about config values, then there's no reason to use XML when it can just be done in code.  .NET has libraries to read and write XML pretty easily, but based on your original question it doesn't sound like that's what you need to do.